# MySQL SUM of a single column with a single row

Tags: mysql, text, sum, row

this question is about MySQL.

I want to know if I can SUM a column from a single row, for example I have a column in which is written "5 21 10", instead of one column for every value (one for 5, one for 21, one for 10), I want to use somehow SUM at this column and it should return 36.

It's possible ? If yes, how ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is better done outside of MySQL.  Relational databases expect each cell to contain one single value.

Comment: I can't SELECT all table, because it will be very big and then make calculations.

Comment: Do you have only 3 values in string or any number of values?

Comment: Any number, I add them from time to time.

Comment: Please tell what you want to achieve? Why you want to do this? so that you might be helped in easier way. Otherwise

Get multiple strings of each value (like '5 21 10') by splitting on spaces. You have to use mysql string splitter like http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/ for this purpose. You will get strings  (like '5' '21' '10') Then loop through all these strings and convert them to a number then add all those numbers. Which is tough one through a query and may be even through using a procedure

Comment: I wanted to make a "Top" with the best Users with most "Wins", the "Wins" are saved like "25 64 1 54 13 2 6 12 42". So I can't easier ... thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

if you know the column names, then just select their sum.

```
SELECT col1 + col2 + col3 FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: yep, SUM() is not what you want

Comment: I know their names, of course, but I want only from one column, let's say it's "Marks" with the values "5 10 5 1" (text). Something like SELECT SUM( `Marks` ) ORDER BY SUM( `Marks` ) LIMIT 100

Comment: I see now, the first explanation was poor, sorry. xD

Comment: If there are three values, why are you storing them in a single cell in the table?  That's not how to do that.